# FN Shortcut keys don't work anymore after changed accidentally

Tags: shortcut-keys

The problem is that the FN + keys were working perfectly, but I accidentally changed the "volume up" to F10 without the FN key (in the system settings, keyboard, shortcuts) but then I changed it back to FN+F10 and the shortcut doesn't work anymore. Later I noticed that every shortcut that I have manually changed to FN + key doesnt work (the shortcut was the same before I changed it); however, if I changed the shortcut to any key without FN then it works perfectly.

So how do I make FN + keys work again????

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could come up with was to delete the hidden folder " .gconf " in the home folder. Deleting it will reset all user specific desktop settings (including the keyboard shortcuts).